# Config::Simple Perl module loop through hash

Tags: perl, hash

I'm using Config::Simple for my App config, I have created `Stats_feeder.cfg` that has a block `[stats_interval]`

```
[stats_interval]
1m = 60
15m = 900
```

And my perl script  `script.pl`

```
my $cfg = new Config::Simple('stats_feeder.cfg') or die Config::Simple->error();

my $hash = $cfg->get_block('stats_interval');
```

When I run `print Dumper($hash);` I get

```
# perl stats_feederv2.pl
$VAR1 = {
          '1m' => '300',
          '15m' => '900',
          '60m' => '3600',
          '30m' => '1800'
        };
```

I can access values using  `$val = $cfg->param('1m');`

I'm trying to loop through this hash and print keys and values, I have tried the following:

```
foreach my $key ( keys %$hash )
{

  print "key $key value $hash{$key}\n";

}
```

I keep getting

```
Global symbol "%hash" requires explicit package name at stats_feederv2.pl line 42.
Execution of stats_feederv2.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$hash{key}` syntax that you use for printing the key's value works when you have a named hash: `%hash`. In your case, you have an anonymous hash, under a hash reference.

To access the key's value in such a case, you should use this syntax: `$hash_ref->{key}`. Change:

```
print "key $key value $hash{$key}\n";
```

To:

```
print "key $key value $hash->{$key}\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

You are dealing with a hash *reference* so you need to use `$hash->{$key}`

An expression like `$hash{$key}` is attempting to access an element of hash `%hash`, and the error message you are getting is because that hash doesn't exist. `$hash` and `%hash` are completely unrelated

Comment: I appreciate your explanation